# How to add radio buttons to radio group

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a TableLayout and in the third column of every row I want to place a radio group.
I build the RadioButtons like this:

```
rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
    rb[k] = new RadioButton(context);
    rg.addView(rb[k]);
}
```

However this cause my app to crash, any ideas?

Comment: Whats the exact problem you are facing? Adding radio group to table layout or adding radio button to radio group?

Comment: The second one.the radio buttons are ok.I cant make them a group,so only one of them can be selected at a time.Everytime i add the "rg.addView(rb[k]);" it crashes.

Comment: Please post where you define `rb`.

Comment: rb = new RadioButton[megethos];
that is some line above the for loop.if you want i can upload the whole code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are building a primitive array with the length of `megethos`, but your loop uses the length `size`. If `megethos` and `size` are different values this can cause many different types of errors... But all of this redundant since a RadioGroup keeps this array up to date for you.

I would try something like this:

```
RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
RadioButton button;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    button = new RadioButton(this);
    button.setText("Button " + i);
    group.addView(button);
}
```

And when you want to reference a button at `index`:

```
group.getChildAt(index);
```

Also please always post your logcat errors, it tells us *exactly* what went wrong and where to look.  Otherwise we have to guess like this.

**Update**

The error is because you are trying to add the same button to two different layouts:

```
tr[k].addView(rb[k]);
rg.addView(rb[k]);
```

a view can only have one parent.  As far as I know you cannot break a RadioGroup apart into multiple views without a lot of customization first.  However a ListView already has the built-in feature setChoiceMode() that behaves like a RadioGroup:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, list);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can easily adapt `simple_list_item_checked` to display the SSID and signal strength. Hope that helps. (If you wait long enough imran khan might cut & paste my answer with graphical change, then claim it as his own again.)

Comment: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/548
thats the code
and thats the errors
http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/548

Comment: Ok, I see what you are trying to do. But those are the same link, could you repost the link to your logcat errors.

Comment: The logcat lead me right to it. I updated my answer. Also an easy way to post the logcat is to highlight the error rows and press crtl-c, then you can paste it to you original question and quick format it there with crtl-k.

Comment: that is what i was looking for.I think that list is much more better choice for my application,than Table.Really,many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have created one demo app in which I have added Radio buttons dynamically and also handled click events.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
RadioGroup radioGroup2;
ArrayList<String> buttonNames;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
    buttonNames = new ArrayList<>();
    buttonNames.add("No Tip");
    buttonNames.add("10%");
    buttonNames.add("20%");
    buttonNames.add("30%");
    radioGroup2.setWeightSum(Float.parseFloat(buttonNames.size() + ""));
    radioGroup2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);


    for (int i = 0; i < buttonNames.size(); ++i) {

        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
        radioButton.setId(i);
        RadioGroup.LayoutParams childParam1 = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f);
        childParam1.setMarginEnd(2);
        radioButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        radioButton.setLayoutParams(childParam1);
        radioButton.setBackground(null);
        radioButton.setText(buttonNames.get(i));
        radioButton.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        radioButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        radioButton.setButtonDrawable(null);
        if (buttonNames.get(i).equals("20%")) {
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
            radioButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            radioButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        radioGroup2.addView(radioButton, childParam1);

    }


    radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i1) {
            RadioButton button = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < buttonNames.size(); ++i) {
                if (i1 == i) {
                    button = (RadioButton) findViewById(i1);
                    button.setChecked(true);
                    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), button.getText() + " checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    button = (RadioButton) findViewById(i);
                    button.setChecked(false);
                    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    button.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
            }
        }
    });


}
```

}